# Why item are not showed when typing anything in the search box?

Tags: android, search, filter, get, fragment

The items are shown until I type anything in the SearchView, then the items disappear.

It seems that the size of fullOffers becomes zero when I type anything; because when I put toast message and It doesn't appear when I put it inside the for loop.

I added getFilter method to the adapter of RecyclerView and linked it with SearchView in the fragemnt.

```
public class OffersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OffersAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable{

    Context context;
    List<offer> offers;
    List<offer> fullOffers;
    public OffersAdapter(List Offers,Context mContext){
        context = mContext;
        offers = Offers;
        fullOffers = new ArrayList<>(Offers);
    }


    public Filter getFilter() {
        return exampleFilter;
    }

    private Filter exampleFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            ArrayList<offer> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(offers);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                    Toast.makeText(context,"item added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // the toast message appears

                for (offer item : fullOffers) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"item added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // it doesn't appear

                    if (item.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;


            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            offers.clear();
            offers.addAll((List) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

}
```

I expect the items to be loaded into "offers" List and appear

Comment: Thanks T001 for the editing

Answer (score 0):

try to change the publishResults method like this:

```
 @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            offers=(List) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```